# Component-selection vs Component-values tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I was about to use a the [component-values](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/component-values/info) tag until I noticed that asides from not having a description, the [component-selection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/component-selection/info) tag actually includes

> selecting specific passive component values for a specific application
>   circuit

So my meta question is does it make sense to have both? should we merge the two? edit their descriptions such that the two are more distinguishable from each other?